# AS3 embedded video player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

I am trying to create an embedded video player, but for some reason it is not connecting the video to the play, pause, stop, or mute button. The page is loading and immediately playing the video, but it is not responding to play or pause or stop or mute. It is calling the video in now, but not responding. Please help!!

```
var video:Video=new Video(480,204);
video.y=stage.stageHeight/2-204/2;
video.x=stage.stageWidth/2-480/2;
addChild(this.video123);

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatusEvent);
function onStatusEvent(stat:Object):void {
    trace(stat.info.code);
}

var meta:Object = new Object();
meta.onMetaData = function(meta:Object){
trace(meta.duration);
};

ns.client=meta;
this.video123.attachNetStream(ns);

this.play1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playFunction);
function playFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play("this.video123");
}

this.stop1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopFunction);
function stopFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.pause();
}

this.pause1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseFunction);
function pauseFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(ns.time);
    ns.togglePause();
}

this.soundButtonUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteFunction);
function muteFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(ns.time);
    var transform:SoundTransform=ns.soundTransform;
    trace("video volume="+ns.soundTransform.volume);
    if (ns.soundTransform.volume!=0) {
        transform.volume=0;
        trace(transform.volume);
        ns.soundTransform=transform;
        trace("video volume="+ns.soundTransform.volume);
        this.soundButtonUp.text="Audio Mute";
    } else {
        transform.volume=1;
        trace(transform.volume);
        ns.soundTransform=transform;
        trace("video volume="+ns.soundTransform.volume);
        this.soundButtonUp.text="";
    }
}
removeChild(this.video123);
```

Answer (score 0):

What the...??  **This.code** worked? So anyway..

1. You've got `var video:Video = new Video(480,204);` but you go on to say `addChild(this.video123);` so where is this **this.video123** coming from??
2. If you want to add the `video` object you just created in the first line then it should be `addChild(video);` or else...
    If **video123** is a movieClip on stage then use `video123.addChild(video);`
3. Further down you should change `this.video123.attachNetStream(ns);` to `video.attachNetStream(ns);`
4. `ns.play("this.video123");` expects a filename, example `ns.play("somefile.mp4");`
    (use FLV or MP4). Now will it surely play/pause the file data etc..
5. I don't know if this line helps anything `removeChild(this.video123);` Why make it just to remove it afterall??

Also stop using **this.** for everything, it's not helping what you are trying to achieve and means something else from what you probably think it does anyway (example are you using multiple **.as** files with code to control the video or run functions? Nope? You dont need to use **this.**. Start by keeping it simple and straight forward. You're not the first to make the mistake though...